# Add property to a DeserializeObject instance?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-5

I am DeserializeObject json to object.
if this is the json:

```
{
"IsSuccess":true,
"ErrorDescription":"the descriptions"
}
```

and I do not know the class.

```
public T Get<T>(string p1)
{
    var response=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(str);
    //how to add property to response here?
    return response
}
```

I want to add a property to response but I do not know if response is null or not.
and I do not know which class is it.

I think it can not so:
If there is BaseClass:

```
public class BaseResp
{

    public bool IsSuccessStatus{get;set;}
}
```

and if `T` is inherited by BaseResp then can I add property to it?

If I can not add property to it then can I return a new instance of BaseResp ?

```
public T Get<T>(string p1)
    {
        var response=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(str);
        if(response==null)
       {
            return new BaseResp();
       }
    }
```

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by "add a property to response"? You can't add additional *properties* to a in-memory type. You can, however, use reflection to *set* an existing property.

Comment: I mean there is no such property in such class but after deserialization I want to there is such a property in the instance.

Comment: you have no idea what kind json is expected? I mean you just know that your json contains "IsSuccess"?

Comment: Yes I have no idea what kind json is expected and all class is inherited a class which contains "IsSuccess" but the json do not contain "IsSuccess"

Comment: tough situation. I suppose first of all you should learn about your possible responses and then make some response models in your side.

Comment: You can't add properties to types at runtime. At most, at runtime, you could construct a new type that inherits from `T`, which adds the new property, but I am not sure what the point would be since the calling code won't know anything about this new property anyway, it would only be discoverable through reflection.